# Nvidia CUDA partially installed

Tags: nvidia

I was trying to install NVIDIA CUDA but I was getting this error as only three are installed and not the rest of two

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using extension manager in VS like this

[image]

OR

Download NVIDIA Nsight Integration from the Visual Studio Marketplace

- Download and Install from the Visual Studio Marketplace
- Close all Visual Studio instances
- Double-click the downloaded extension (vsix file) to initiate the installation
- Specify each version of Visual Studio to which the extension should be installed